# Delphi Check variable value in Type Declaration

Tags: delphi, types, typechecking

How can I determine if the value of a variable is within the range of a Type Declaration. 
Ex.

```
Type
  TManagerType = (mtBMGR, mtAMGR, mtHOOT);

...

var
  ManagerType: TManagerType;

....


procedure DoSomething;
begin
  if (ManagerType in TManagerType) then
    DoSomething
  else
    DisplayErrorMessage;
end;
```

Thanks, Pieter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
InRange: Boolean;
ManagerType: TManagerType;
...
InRange := ManagerType in [Low(TManagerType)..High(TManagerType)];
```

---

As Nickolay O. noted - whilst boolean expression above directly corresponds to:

```
(Low(TManagerType) <= ManagerType) and (ManagerType <= High(TManagerType))
```

compiler *does not* perform optimization on checking membership against immediate set based on single subrange. So, [maturely] optimized code will be less elegant.

Comment: That's not a fastest approach, since it requires construction of set, and checking inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a variable of type TManagerType has to be in that range since that's how Pascal enumerated types work.  The only way it could not be is if you have done something naughty behind the compiler's back.

Another way to write this would be:

```
InRange(ord(ManagerType), ord(low(ManagerType)), ord(high(ManagerType)))
```

Comment: You are right, but I was thinking that someone might try something like "ManagerType := TManagerType(10)".

Comment: You need not to do that!  If you worry about that happening then you'll find that your codebase is 90% validation!  You need to define trust boundaries (e.g. deserialization, user input) and validate the data at the boundaries.  After that such checking becomes counter-productive.  I call it paranoid programming!

Comment: +1 @David I've found worse examples of this kind of second-guessing long after the original developer had departed. Checking the value of a variable immediately after setting it. Calling methods twice just to make sure they "took". At the time I categorized it as "overly defensive" I think paranoid programming sounds better.

Comment: @codeelegance Wow, that sounds ultra paranoid!  There really are a lot of poor practitioners around.  One of my colleagues refers to this paranoid programming as "the belt AND the braces" which I also find satisfying.

Comment: There's no harm in making this kind of check with an Assert() call. That's a way to document that the condition would be false only if there is a bug somewhere in the code. It *should* be obvious that this isn't a data validation check. (Although unfortunately some lazy programmers incorrectly use assertions for data validation, especially if the condition could theoretically fail but almost certainly won't in practice.)

Comment: @ian the harm is the immense clutter

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Obviously there's a balance to be struck, and clutter is subjective. It also depends on how much you trust yourself not to make silly mistakes, and how much you value your time hunting them down when you do :-)

Comment: @ian Not really. If you assert against every possible error then your code becomes unreadable. You need to take gross action to get an enumeration out of range. No point defending against such errors. Otherwise your program will have more assertions than real code.

Answer (score -1):

You should check this via:
if mType > High(TManagerType) then ...